# C# - Custom program buttons?

Tags: c#, winforms, button

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Display the minimize and maximize buttons on a sizable tool window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995172/display-the-minimize-and-maximize-buttons-on-a-sizable-tool-window)
> [How to add an extra button to the window's title bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841180/how-to-add-an-extra-button-to-the-windows-title-bar)

Hey guys i'm making a program and i'm just wondering if it is possible to add your own buttons to the program "head" i'll call it. Like this default windows borderstyle:

[image]

If you still don't get what i mean, I want to add more buttons like the "Minimize" and "Maximize" buttons to this borderstyle:

[image]

If you could tell me how or point me in the right direction i would appreciate it.

Comment: Yes, it is definetely possible, use Win32 Interop in C#, and register for invalidate regions & override form's WndProc

Comment: That is called the title bar.

Comment: no thats no duplicate, we are talking about adding custom titlebar buttons

Comment: This should help you out.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42460/custom-titlebars-chrome-in-a-winforms-app

Comment: yes, this one is the same, i think

Answer (score 2):

I think it can help you to achieve your end:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/mintraybtn.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Although it is possible by using the WinAPI, I would discourage you from doing that.

First off, it is not easy, and it requires a pretty good practice of windowing, messaging and similar API stuffs. Secondly, you should take in account the different "styles" that the various "Windows" offers. You know, you may switch among many color combination from within the desktop settings panel.

Instead, I would recommend you to create a borderless window, so that you may place any button with worrying. Also, I'd suggest to choose a very specific styling, so that the result will be aesthetically pleasant for the user's eyes.

Hope it helps.

Cheers